# Smartcard communication with protocol t1

Tags: c#, communication, smartcard

Hi everyone i've got another questions for you : )

I want to communicate smartcard with protocol t=1. i am using windows smartcard api (winscard.dll) and C#. i've got

SCardEstablishContext(), SCardListReaders(), SCardConnect(), SCardStatus(), SCardTransmit(), SCardDisconnect(), SCardReleaseContext() functions for transmitting data.

i want to select the master file (mf) with the below code

```
SCARD_IO_REQUEST sendreq,recvreq;

byte[] sendbuff = { 0x00, 0xA4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x3F, 0x00 };

sendreq.protocol = SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1;
sendreq.pciLength = 8;
recvreq.protocol = SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1;
recvreq.pciLength = 8;

byte[] RecvBuff = new byte[258];
int recvbufflen = 2;

SCardTransmit(hCard, ref sendreq, ref sendbuff[0], sendbuff.Length, ref recvreq, ref RecvBuff[0], ref recvbufflen);
```

the response must be 9000 for the successful task but i receive 6A86 (invalid ins parameters).

my questions are:

1- Why am i receiving this response?

2- Do i have to change the protocol with pts command if yes why? (the card supports only t1)

3- the protocol t = 1 frame must be prologue field + information field + epilogue field. But i dont add the prologue and epilogue bytes to sendbuff. is it necessary to add them to sendbuff while using windows api?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem its because of the parameters p1 and p2. Inspite of receiving 'invalid parameters' i thought the parameters were correct. So i was searching the mistake somewhere else.

For selecting file, the parameters must be 0x02 and 0x0C.

Edit: afer the guidot's comment i realized that i didnt use these parameters to select master file. (tried it but changed later) To select EF under the MF :

```
byte[] sendbuff = {0x00, 0xA4, 0x02, 0x0C, 0x02, id1, id2}
```

thanks to guidot..

Comment: Actually P1/P2 equalling zero is also correct (in the sense of standard-compliant) stating an arbitrary DF/EF to be selected, but as always, no card is obliged to support it. That command would produce a response, however (as opposed to P2=0xC), and since you supplied no LE byte, that mismatch will possibly provoke an error message. 6A86 would not be my first guess for that but has also some justification.